# Object of type <> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django

I am running a website using Django . Here is views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    registered=False
    failed_ref=False
    wrong_ref=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        if 'city' in request.POST:
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
            else:
                print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
         profile_form=ProfileForm()
    return JsonResponse({'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered,
                                                    'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref},safe=False)
```

When i try to get, Json Response, i am getting

> Object of type ProfileForm is not JSON Serializable

My `ProfileForm()`:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model=Profile
    widgets = {
        'address_line_1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Door No,Building'}),
        'address_line_2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Area,Locality'}),
    }
    fields=('first_name','last_name','mobile_no','email','address_line_1','address_line_2','postal_code','city','country','image','referral_contact','promo_coupon','ic')
```

How to get JSON Response for this?

Comment: is it happening for all cases? if not, what is the value of `request.POST` in cases where it is getting error?

Comment: Have you looked at Django JSON encoder? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396494/why-the-form-is-not-json-serializable`

Answer (score 1):

you need to serialize the data.

from django.core import serializers

```
data = serializers.serialize('xml', Profile.objects.all(), fields=('first_name','last_name','mobile_no','email','address_line_1','address_line_2','postal_code','city','country','image','referral_contact','promo_coupon','ic'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Form class is not JSON Serializable, you should use [cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) instead

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False
    failed_ref = False
    wrong_ref = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'city' in request.POST:
            user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()
                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = user
                # use cleaned_data
                profile_form.cleaned_data['user'] = user_form.cleaned_data
            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return JsonResponse(
        {
            'profile_form': profile_form.cleaned_data,
            'registered': registered,
            'failed_ref': failed_ref,
            'wrong_ref': wrong_ref
        },
        safe=False)
```